# Pager Duty configuration to ring when receiving a call

Tags: android, pagerduty

I use Pager Duty but I'm struggling to have it ringing when I receive a notification / call. I use my phone in vibration mode most of the time and in particular over night.

To sum it up I'd like to get woken up from a Pager Duty alert but not from a Whatts App message.

Is it possible to achieve this from either Pager Duty or Android configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both suggestions I have, you can do some setup in PagerDuty to ensure it will call or push to your mobile on high and/or low urgency incidents. It's in your user profile (upper right of PagerDuty's page) and under notification settings. https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/user-profile#notification-rules

If you are using the mobile app for PagerDuty, tap the user settings and make sure you have defined the High/Low urgency sounds. In addition, select the "Override Do not Disturb".  Care on the override system volume though, PagerDuty's amp goes to 11.  It will only override high urgency stuff though which is usually all we need to worry about at 2am in the morning.

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/mobile-app-settings#android-9-override-system-volume-and-do-not-disturb

If you just have SMS or Phone notifications then you'll want to grab the vCard for PagerDuty's notification numbers and create a contact from it.  Then setup your phone to allow that contact to ring while others vibrate. This could be just giving PagerDuty's contact a ringtone or looking into the system settings for allowing favorited contacts to override do not disturb. Keep in mind, without the app to keep the vCard updated you'll have to periodically update it yourself.

https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/notification-phone-numbers